# how Bind Resquest to Domain class in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I don't like the command objects because have a lot duplicated code..

I want do something like this in vraptor.

this is the Vraptor code a java framework

```
 <form action="<c:url value='/produtos/adiciona'/>">
Nome:             <input type="text" name="produto.nome" /><br/>
Descrição:    <input type="text" name="produto.descricao" /><br/>
Preço:            <input type="text" name="produto.preco" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>

@Resource
public class ProdutosController {
//...
public void adiciona(Produto produto) {
    dao.adiciona(produto);
}
}
```

source http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/en/docs/ten-minute-guide/

In grails don't works why??? anyone now about this

```
class User {
String login
String password
}

<g:form name="form" url="[controller:'user',action:'login']">
    Login <input type="text" name="user.login"/><br/>
    Senha <input type="password" name="user.password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/>
</g:form>

def login(User user){
render("result ${user.login} and ${user.password}")
}
```

The response is null "result null and null"

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with grails, like:

```
void adiciona() {
    Produto produto = new Produto(params.produto) // 'produto.' is a prefix at this case
    dao.adiciona(produto);
}
```

See docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding

Btw, I should warn you that this way could cause some security issues, because user will be able to update any field, even internal, fields you don't want to be filled from user input.

Comment: but you can validade the field using the custom validator clojures if nescessary, can you show one sample?

Comment: you can, but as a result you'll invent your own command class :) show sample of validation? it's here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html

Comment: but i dont't want one comand class i just want bind the domain class with the request can you understand?

Comment: your example works but the line Produto produto = new Produto(params.produto) is in my opinion the boilerplate code, the framework shold make a new object for you and populate and call validade method for you